Why is my IPYNB file opened as IPY File (raw JSON) in Jupyter Notebook?
When I open an IPYNB file (downloaded from internet) in Jupyter Notebook then it displays as a raw JSON file instead of the usual interactive notebook view.
it is too confusing and frustrating.
Anyone know the reason?

I just figured out the issue. It turned out that the file I downloaded from the internet had a problem with either the file name or, more specifically, its location on the hard drive.
However, when I renamed the file to something shorter and opened it in Jupyter, it displayed correctly in the usual interactive view.
You can also try moving the file to a higher-level folder (this is helpful if the folder names in the file path are too long).

Others looking for more context, see here.
